# "xcrun: error: active developer path… does not exist, use xcode-select --switch" when trying to run git. How to fix?

Tags: xcode, git, macos

I have been trying to instal the Git on my mac, But every time I use the command $git --version.

I get the following error

**xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use `xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools (or see `man xcode-select`)**

I have already installed the Xcode on my mac for iOS App development.
I am not sure what this error is trying to say.

Comment: Are the XCode command line tools installed (https://developer.apple.com/downloads/)? Please describe how you installed Git. I have switched to HomeBrew as a package manager and have been really happy with it. If you want to try it out, I have some instructions here: http://steve-tarver-mac.blogspot.com/2015/05/install-homebrew.html.

Comment: So did you do what that message said and run `xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app`? And if so, what happened? You should describe that in your question.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I tried, but it says
sudo: xcode-select: command not found

Comment: @starver I just installed the git from http://git-scm.com/download/mac

Comment: So if you do `ls /usr/bin/xcode*` it shows nothing, right? If so then you must not have XCode installed correctly, and you need to try re-installing it—from the App Store, or starting at https://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/xcode/id497799835

Comment: @sideshowbarker it is showing 
/usr/bin/xcodebuild /usr/bin/xcodeproj

Comment: OK, then there must be some problem with your PATH, right? If you do `echo $PATH`, it must not contain `/usr/bin/`. If your PATH did contain  `/usr/bin/`, then you wouldn’t get  `xcode-select: command not found`.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Please ask this in a more appropriate place.

Comment: @rmaddy what according to you is the appropriate place to ask this question? everybody is replying.

Comment: Try http://apple.stackexchange.com or the Apple developer forums.

Comment: @rmaddy ok, I will post there too. Thanks for the Downvote

Comment: Bad assumption. Not my down vote. But it's quite common for off-topic questions to be down voted. You really should delete this question since it is off-topic.

Comment: @rmaddy I will wait untill somebody else see this post and give some useful info. I will delete once I solve this. I have already posted http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206537/unable-to-install-git-on-my-mac
and sorry for the bad assumption, my bad

Comment: @sideshowbarker it gave me the output containg /usr/bin/

Comment: @sideshowbarker 
I used 
$ DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/"
$ export DEVELOPER_DIR
and now it works perfectly, I really donot know its meanning, and every time i restart my mac, I have to run these commands again

Comment: @Jeev just add those lines your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile and then you won’t need to re-enter them manually after restarts.

Comment: Actually it seems that you should run it like this once: `sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`, and then after that it will remember that setting itself (and you won’t need the DEVELOPER_DIR environment variable to be set.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So from discussion in the comments above, it seems the right fix here is just to run the command `/usr/bin/xcode-select -switch` once (i.e., run it with the full path to the executable, rather than just as `xcode-select`) with `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/` as the argument:

```
sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

After running that once, everything should work as expected from then on.

Comment: I did this also i checked my xcode path by `xcode-select -print-path ` and gave me 
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`. But when I ran you solution command it shows `xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'`

Comment: I get the same result as @NoobCoder.  Does anyone have an update?

Answer (score 23):

**My case:**

I removed XCode. JetBrains integration with git - breaks. Found this error in terminal.

**My soltuion:**

I don't want to download XCode to restore PyCharm. So I ran:

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

and reboot your computer.

Comment: If you, like me, deleted the application Xcode and still wants to use the command line tools – this is the solution that works! Thx!

Answer (score 5):

Try this below answer. It's worked for me.

Open your Xcode **Preferences**,

--> Select **Locations**

--> Select your specific Xcode version in **Command Line Tools**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It was easier for me to let Xcode pick the install location of Command Line Tools for me, instead of the other way around. After downloading the `.xip` file from the Apple Developer downloads page, expanding the compressed contents, and installing Xcode.App, I was able to open it using Spotlight.

[image: xcode in spotlight]

And open preferences:

[image]

And select my Command Line Tools under "Locations".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can install `git` via the `brew` package manager for Mac.  I recommend installing software this way since it's a great way to manage your installed packages in one place.  For example, you can do `brew update` to get a list of the latest package updates, or `brew upgrade` to upgrade all of your software installed through `brew`.

1. To install brew, open a terminal window and run:

   ```
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```
2. Update your brew packages with `brew update`
3. Install git with `brew install git`

Answer (score 1):

I had installed git, then returned to a terminal window open prior to the installation.  I try running command `git --version` and this raised error message below.  To resolve, I ran command `source /etc/profile` in same terminal window. BTW, terminal window is inside my Webstorm and my end goal is to `git init` and setup git for my new reactjs project.  Happy coding!

The error:

```
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use \`xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app\` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools (or see \`man xcode-select\`)
```